# Associations Grails/Gorm

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have the the domain classes Rep and Bill. Bill has two fields of the type Rep called sponsor and cosponsor. I have set up the association in Bill as `static hasMany = [sponsor: Rep, cosponsor: Rep]`. When ever I try to save I get `NULL not allowed for column "BILL_SPONSOR_ID"; SQL statement: insert into bill_rep (bill_cosponsor_id, rep_id) values (?, ?) [23502-193]`. I understand that for some reason the the correct ids are not getting inserted. I have tried set both sponsor and cosponsor to nullable but I have not been able to get around it. Any idea as to what I am doing wrong?

```
class Bill {
    String billPre
    String number
    String billName
    Integer dateIntro
    String summary

    static hasMany = [cosponsor: Rep, sponsor: Rep, committee: Committee]

    static constraints = {
        cosponsor nullable: true
        sponsor nullable: true
    }
    String toString() {
        billName
    }
}



class Rep {
    String name
    String party
    String congress
    Integer district
    String state
    String repEmail
    String street
    String phone
    Integer congStart
    Integer congEnd
    Integer congNumStart
    Integer congNumEnd







     static constraints = {
            name()
            party()
            district()
            congress inList: ["House", "Senate"]
            state inList: ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming']
            party inList: ["Republican", "Democrat"]
            repEmail email: true
            street()
            phone()
            congStart()
            congEnd()
            congNumStart()
            congNumEnd()

        }

        String toString() {
            name
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you update your question with your domain class structure?

Comment: @Prakash I have added the domain classes

Comment: How are you attempting the save? Is it Bill.addToSponser()